# Multi-threaded input processing

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to using multithreading and I am working on a program that handles mouse movement, it consists of two threads, the main thread gets the input and stores the mouse position in a fixed location and the child thread loops through that location to get the value. So how do I reduce CPU utilization, I am using conditional variables to achieve this, is there a better way to do this? It seems that adding a delay to the subthreads would also work

```
void Engine::InputManager::MouseMove(const MouseMoveEvent& ev)
{
    cur_mouse_ev_.x_ = ev.x_;
    cur_mouse_ev_.y_ = ev.y_;
    cv_.notify_all();
}
void Engine::InputManager::ProcessInput(MouseMoveEvent* ev)
{
    while (true)
    {
        cv_.wait(u_mutex_);
        float dx = static_cast<float>(ev->x_ - pre_mouse_pos[0]) * 0.25f;
        float dy = static_cast<float>(ev->y_ - pre_mouse_pos[1]) * 0.25f;
        g_pGraphicsManager->CameraRotateYaw(dx);
        pre_mouse_pos[0] = ev->x_;
        pre_mouse_pos[1] = ev->y_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `std::condition_variable` is a good and efficient way to achieve what you want.

However - you implementation has the following issue:
`std::condition_variable` suffers from **spurious wakeups**. You can read about it here: [Spurious wakeup - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

The correct way to use a condition variable requires:

1. To add a variable (`bool` in your case) to hold the "condition" you are waiting for. The variable should be updated under a lock using the mutex.
2. Again under a lock: calling `wait` in a loop until the variable satisfies the condition you are waiting for. If a spurious wakeup will occur, the loop will ensure getting into the waiting state again. BTW - `wait` method has an overload that gets a predicate for the condition, and loops for you.

You can see some code examples here:
[Condition variable examples](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables).

A minimal sample that demonstrates the flow:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex              mtx;
std::condition_variable cond_var;
bool                    ready{ false };

void handler()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cond_var.wait(lck, []() { return ready; }); // will loop internally to handle spurious wakeups
    }
    // Handle data ...
}

void main()
{
    std::thread t(handler);

    // Prepare data ...
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        ready = true;
    }
    cond_var.notify_all();
    t.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you could try using a [semaphore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore), for (possibly) better performance
2. instead of 2 threads, you could try using coroutines (standard or your [own](https://github.com/user1095108/cr2)), for less memory consumption. A thread needs a stack frame, that's several MBytes at least. A coroutine may not need anything extra.

Comment: A thread doesn't need a stack _frame._ A thread needs an entire _stack._

Comment: I prefer to write stack frame, as there is no actual data structure in use.

Comment: FWIW the thread-implementation itself uses data structures, some of which get pushed onto the beginning of the thread's stack.

Comment: we don't know what implementation you are talking about. I believe stack frame is less ambiguous than just "stack". It is obvious a stack frame refers to memory, not a data structure.

Comment: Re, "I prefer to write stack frame." You will have a hard time talking to other software developers so long as you insist on calling things by whatever name suits your preference instead of using the names that everybody else uses.

Comment: I tried to find an exact, reputable definition of "stack frame" and could not. To me, it's just a "contiguous region of memory used for local variables". You are welcome to write your own answer to the OPs question, rather than comment on mine. How about that?

Comment: Also, note that the C++ Standard does not include definitions of "stack", "heap", or "stack frame" for that matter. Yet, you know everything about them.