# Multithreading in C++ - Display animation until another thread has completed

Tags: c++, multithreading, animation, stdthread

Preface: this is my first attempt at writing a program in any language with multi-threading. I have no prior experience with std::thread, or with describing multi-threaded programs at all. Please let me know if you need more information to answer this question, or if I can reword anything to make my question clearer.

Suppose I have a simple animation function `animate`, which (for now) runs indefinitely; and another function `task`, which represents some arbitrary code to execute.

```
#include <string>

// a simple rotating stick animation: | -> / -> - -> \

void animate()
{
  std::string syms = "|/-\\";
  while (true)
  {
    for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < syms.length(); ++ii)
    {
      std::cout << syms[ii];
      std::cout << std::string(1, '\b');
    }
  }
}

// arbitrary function

void task()
{
  // code to do something else goes here
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // execute task and animate at the same time;
  // return from animate once task has completed
  return 0;
}
```

How can I use `std::thread` (or some other header/library) to allow `task` and `animate` to communicate with each other, such that `task` runs in the "background" and `animate` runs until `task` has completed?

Comment: *I have no prior experience with std::thread, or with describing multi-threaded programs at all* -- Multithreaded programming is not simple, and can't really be learned by trial and error.  You need to invest in good books, materials, and prior, working examples on MT programming, and not go about this in an adhoc fashion.  You have syncrhonization primiatives, condition variables, atomic variables, and a whole host of other things that requires much more than learning how to start a thread.  That's why MT programmers are usually paid much more than their single-thread counterparts.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Cool. That doesn't answer my question. I'm asking for the simplest of starting points. I can't learn if I don't know what to search for, or how to apply any of it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think if this was for a rigorous professional project, your comment seems appropriate. I get the sense that this is an educational project for fun, and in that case I think small ad-hoc examples are much more encouraging than dumping on a mountain of theory.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi Even for the MT "toy" example, it is better to see how another program accomplishes what the OP is attempting to accomplish.  Maybe it's me, but I have yet to see someone just walk into programming anything MT with no material(s) already in hand to learn from.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If you'd like to help, you're more than welcome to modify any of the code in my example to help get me on the right track. If not, then I'd like to ask that you stop commenting. Thanks!

Comment: @RandyPrice The comment section is for comments, thus I commented specifically on your endeavor.  If you want answers, that goes in the answer section, not comment section.  I already mentioned things you should learn about, such as synchronization primitives (like mutex) and condition variables.  To have threads communicate with each other and determine when one stops is usually done by using condition variables, which are available in C++11 and above.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You see, this is exactly what I'm looking for, but since I'm new, I had no idea what to search for. A simple link to this in the first place would've sufficed. Thank you

Comment: @RandyPrice - you can have a look at my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882767/multi-threaded-input-processing/71883693#71883693. The problem is different,  but it shows a basic example of using `std::thread` and a `condition_variable` that might help you learn about the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken your example code and tried to fill in the blanks from your intention with `std::thread`. I've added some comments inline to explain what's going on. If something's not clear, or I got it wrong, feel free to ask in the comments.

I want to stress though that this example *only* uses `std::thread` to create and join a separate thread in a toy example.
It *does not* synchronize shared data between threads in a correct way.
Shared data in MT environments is where things get hairy and the worst thing is that it can create some of the hardest to debug bugs out there. That's why the books and working examples are important for any substantial multithreaded program.

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

// a simple rotating stick animation: | -> / -> - -> \

//
void animate(bool * should_animate)
{
  // Using this namespace lets us use the "100ms" time literal in the sleep_for() function argument.
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  std::string syms = "|/-\\";
  while (*should_animate)
  {
    for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < syms.length(); ++ii)
    {
      std::cout << syms[ii];
      std::cout << std::string(1, '\b');

      // I had to flush cout so that the animation would show up
      std::cout.flush();
      // I added some delay here so that the animation is more visible
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }
  }
}

// arbitrary function

void task()
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  // I have this thread waiting for 2 seconds to simulate a lot of work being done
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

  // This line creates a thread from the animate() function
  // The std::thread constructor is flexible, in that it can take a function with any number and type of arguments and
  // make a thread out of it
  // Once the thread is created, it gets sent to the operating system for scheduling right away in a separate thread
  // I'm passing in a pointer to `should_animate` to use that value as a basic way to communicate to the animate thread to signal when it should stop running.
  // I'm doing this to keep the example simple, but I stress that this isn't a good idea for larger scale programs
  // Better to use propper signals or event queues
  bool should_animate = true;
  std::thread thread_animate(animate, &should_animate);

  // This line creates a thread for the worker task
  // That separate thread can be referenced by tis std::thread object
  // Once the functions finish running, the thread associated with it is "joined"
  std::thread thread_task(task);

  // 'join' pauses the main thread to wait for the associated thread to finish running in the background.
  thread_task.join();

  // By this point in the program, the `task()` function has finished running, so we can flag
  // the animate task to finish running so its thread can be joined
  should_animate = false;
  // Wait for the animate thread to get the message and finish
  thread_animate.join();


  std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

If you want to take it a little further, here's some links I'd recommend.

- This was the best tutorial I could find in the first page of google (most results seemed bad). Seems like a good jumping off point https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/
- cppreference is the best C++ reference site I know of, and I usually have at least one tab on it all day. Because it is reference, its difficult to dig straight into it. Each section header of this page covers one multithreaded topics. "Threads" and "Mutual Exclusion" are the most common things uses in MT. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread