# c++11 condition_variable::wait() doesn't return when notified and predicate is true

Tags: c++, locking, predicate, notify, condition-variable

I have this test code, I expect that Thread-1 will wait for Thread-2 to notify and set condition to `true` and then finish. I hope it would print (Step 1) to (Step 5)

```
#include <atomic>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
    atomic_bool ab(false);
    mutex m; // lock object
    condition_variable c;
    auto f1 = async(launch::async, [&](){
        unique_lock<mutex> _(m);
        cout << "(Step 1)\n";
        c.wait(_, [&]{return (bool)ab;});
        cout << "(Step 5)\n";
    });
    auto f2 = async(launch::async, [&](){
        this_thread::sleep_for(1s); // wait for f1 starting
        unique_lock<mutex> _(m);
        cout << "(Step 2) signal\n";
        c.notify_one();
        cout << "(Step 3) \n";
    });
    this_thread::sleep_for(3s); // condition is waiting for "ab = true"
    cout << "(Step 4) \n";
    ab = true;
    f1.wait();
    f2.wait();
    return 0;
}
```

But in fact in prints:

```
(Step 1)
(Step 2) signal
(Step 3) 
(Step 4)
```

and hangs, never prints `(Step 5)`. Why my `condition_variable::wait()` didn't return?

Comment: `ab` is set to true by the main **after** `c.notify_one()` is called. Thus when `wait` is checking the condition it is still not `true` (and you miss the notification).

Comment: A side note: naming a variable "_" is a bit strange (will probably confuse some readers of your code).

Comment: Usually you should couple singaling the `condition_variable` with setting the variable holding the "condition". See an example in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882767/multi-threaded-input-processing/71883693#71883693.

Comment: Side note: condition variables provide synchronization. When they're used correctly, the variables involved in deciding whether it's time to wake up don't need their own synchronization. `ab` can be just plain `bool`.