# How to properly wait for condition variable in C++?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, wait, condition-variable

In trying to create an asynchronous I/O file reader in C++ under Linux. The example I have has two buffers. The first read blocks. Then, for each time around the main loop, I asynchronously launch the IO and call `process()` which runs the simulated processing of the current block. When processing is done, we wait for the condition variable. The idea is that the asynchronous handler should notify the condition variable.

Unfortunately the `notify` seems to happen before `wait`, and it seems like this is not the way the condition variable `wait()` function works. How should I rewrite the code so that the loop waits until the asynchronous io has completed?

```
#include <aio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

constexpr uint32_t blockSize = 512;

mutex readMutex;

condition_variable cv;

int fh;
int bytesRead;

void process(char* buf, uint32_t bytesRead) {
  cout << "processing..." << endl;
  usleep(100000);
}

void aio_completion_handler(sigval_t sigval) {
  struct aiocb* req = (struct aiocb*)sigval.sival_ptr;

  // check whether asynch operation is complete
  if (aio_error(req) == 0) {
    int ret = aio_return(req);
        bytesRead = req->aio_nbytes;
    cout << "ret == " << ret << endl;
    cout << (char*)req->aio_buf << endl;
  }
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> readLock(readMutex);
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

void thready() {
  char* buf1 = new char[blockSize];
  char* buf2 = new char[blockSize];
  aiocb cb;
  char* processbuf = buf1;
  char* readbuf = buf2;
  fh = open("smallfile.dat", O_RDONLY);
  if (fh < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("cannot open file!");
  }

  memset(&cb, 0, sizeof(aiocb));
  cb.aio_fildes = fh;
  cb.aio_nbytes = blockSize;
  cb.aio_offset = 0;

  // Fill in callback information
  /*
  Using SIGEV_THREAD to request a thread callback function as a notification
  method
  */
  cb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_attributes = nullptr;
  cb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  cb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_function = aio_completion_handler;
  /*
  The context to be transmitted is loaded into the handler (in this case, a
  reference to the aiocb request itself). In this handler, we simply refer to
  the arrived sigval pointer and use the AIO function to verify that the request
  has been completed.
  */
  cb.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &cb;

  int currentBytesRead = read(fh, buf1, blockSize);  // read the 1st block

  while (true) {
    cb.aio_buf = readbuf;
    aio_read(&cb);  // each next block is read asynchronously
    process(processbuf, currentBytesRead);  // process while waiting
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> readLock(readMutex);
            cv.wait(readLock);
        }
        currentBytesRead = bytesRead; // make local copy of global modified by the asynch code
    if (currentBytesRead < blockSize) {
      break;  // last time, get out
    }
    cout << "back from wait" << endl;
    swap(processbuf, readbuf);     // switch to other buffer for next time
    currentBytesRead = bytesRead;  // create local copy
  }

  delete[] buf1;
  delete[] buf2;
}

int main() {
  try {
    thready();
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    cerr << e.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A condition variable is more of a "signal" that something changed not an actual value itself. You miss that actual value, you could add a boolean. Initialize to false, just before notify you set it to true and in the wait you have to wait with a predicate. e.g. `cv.wait(readLock,[]{return your_boolean; }); Or in other words to make it work you need : a mutex, a condition variable, a variable and a predicate.

Comment: Your condition variable has no associated predicate conditions; that's an instant red-flag. You're using it as a remedial signaling mechanism. And your mutex is basically protecting *nothing*. Related, from what I see you also don't need two mutex objects for this either.

Comment: It's not exact duplicates, but you can see some usage examples for `std::condition_variable` in my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882767/multi-threaded-input-processing/71883693#71883693, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260569/minimal-mutexes-for-stdqueue-producer-consumer/72261477#72261477.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A condition variable should generally be used for

- waiting until it is possible that the predicate (for example a shared variable) has changed, and
- notifying waiting threads that the predicate may have changed, so that waiting threads should check the predicate again.

However, you seem to be attempting to use the state of the condition variable itself as the predicate. This is not how condition variables are supposed to be used and may lead to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) such as those described in your question. Another reason to always check the predicate is that spurious wakeups are possible with condition variables.

In your case, it would probably be appropriate to create a shared variable

```
bool operation_completed = false;
```

and use that variable as the predicate for the condition variable. Access to that variable should always be controlled by the mutex.

You can then change the lines

```
{
    unique_lock<mutex> readLock(readMutex);
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

to

```
{
    unique_lock<mutex> readLock(readMutex);
    operation_completed = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

and change the lines

```
{
    unique_lock<mutex> readLock(readMutex);
    cv.wait(readLock);
}
```

to:

```
{
    unique_lock<mutex> readLock(readMutex);
    while ( !operation_completed )
        cv.wait(readLock);
}
```

Instead of

```
while ( !operation_completed )
    cv.wait(readLock);
```

you can also write

```
cv.wait( readLock, []{ return operation_completed; } );
```

which is equivalent. See the documentation of [`std::condition_varible::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) for further information.

Of course, `operation_completed` should also be set back to `false` when appropriate, while the mutex is locked.

Comment: More idiomatic than the `while ( !operation_completed )` loop would be `cv.wait(readLock, []{ return operation_completed; });`

Comment: @user4581301: Thanks for pointing that out. I have incorporated your comment into my answer. I will not delete the `while` loop though, because in this case, it is important to show OP what happens "under the hood".